What to do when you realize you've overfit?
This is hypothetical and I would like to hear what people do when the get to the test set and realize they've overfit. Of course, preventing overfitting in the first place is ideal.
You're working on a prediction problem and you split your data into a Train, Validation, and Training set. You're MSE on Validation is within a reasonable value of you're train MSE. However, when you get to your test set, the MSE is very poor. What do you do?
Some Ideas I have

Use a less complex model or regularize more
Make sure there are no common issues: data leakage, forward looking bias, etc.
Get more data

What else?
Say you still do all of this and the model still seems to be overfitting.

Re: "Say you still do all this..." those things are all hard to do, so I would be more concerned with whether I had done them correctly rather than looking for other things to try.

Okay, but in the case where you have done them correctly...what do you do?
